# Geometrically irreducible schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, arithmetic-geometry

$\newcommand\spec{\operatorname{Spec}}$Hartshorne Exercise II.3.15 a) states the following:

Let $X$ be a scheme of finite type over a field $k$ then the following are equivalent (in which case we call $X$ geometrically irreducible):

1. $X_{\bar k}$ is irreducible, where $\bar k$ is the algebraic closure of $k$
2. $X_{k_s}$ is irreducible, where $k_s$ is the separable closure of $k$
3. $X_K$ is irreducible for any field extension $K/k$.

where we have the typical notation abuse that we also see with algebraic varieties in classical algebraic geometry $X_K := X \times_{\spec k} \spec K$ for any field extension $K/k$.

I'm not really curious about how to answer this question (but maybe someone can still give a hint). What I am really curious about is why is it assumed that $X$ is finite type over 
$k$ (So $X$ is finitely covered by spectra of finitely generated $k$-algebras). I'm not sure why for instance locally of finite type (or even a less strict condition) is not sufficient or is it that the proof is easier if we assume $X$ is of finite type over $k$?

Comment: Good questions. Have you looked at the corresponding stacks project page? It appears that the finiteness hypotheses can be removed entirely, if I'm not reading this wrong. https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0364 But I don't have a great explanation for why Hartshorne wrote the question assuming that $X$ is of finite type.

Comment: I think the stacks project only talks about separable algebraic closures, but I don't know if that matters

Comment: I took a peek at the stacks tag. Maybe it has to do with the succeeding questions b and c which I haven't yet read. Because the "finite type" is stated before stating a),b) and c).

Comment: @Notone: I think you just need this to finish it from there: If $k$ is a seperably closed field and $L/k$ is a field extension and $A$ is a $k$-algebra such that $\mathrm{Spec A}$ is irreducible then $\mathrm{Spec}(A\otimes_k L)$ is irreducible.